# How can I add a related field to serializer instance?

Tags: django

I have the following model + serializer where I send a post request to create a new model instance. The user sending the post request is related to a `Company` which I want to pass as related model instance to the serializer.

But how to actually define this instance and attach it to the serializer instance within the post view?

```
# views.py

class OfferList(APIView):
    """
    List all Offers or create a new Offer related to the authenticated user
    """
    def get(self, request):
        offers = Offer.objects.filter(company__userprofile__user=request.user)
        serializer = OfferSerializer(offers, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = OfferSerializer(data=request.data)
        
        # Add related company instance
        company = Company.objects.get(userprofile__user=request.user)
        serializer['company'] = company # this doesn't work
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data,
                            status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

```
# offer/models.py

class Offer(models.Model):
    """
    A table to store Offer instances
    """

    # Relations
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

..
```

```
# serializers.py

class OfferSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Offer
        fields = '__all__'
```

```
user/models.py

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    """
    Extends Base User via 1-1 for profile information
    """
    # Relations
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way is to pass your company instance through your serializer. So maybe changing your post method to something like:

```
from rest_framework.generics import get_object_or_404

def post(self, request):
    serializer = OfferSerializer(data=request.data)
    
    # Add related company instance
    
    if serializer.is_valid():
        company = get_object_or_404(Company, userprofile__user=request.user)  # raising 404 exception if related company does not exist, 
        # and you're sure that there is one and only one company for this user not more!
        
        serializer.save(company=company)
        return Response(serializer.data,
                        status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

and then change your serializer fields to exclude company field from them (because you are already sending this data through your serializer):

```
class OfferSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Offer
        fields = ["some_field", "other_field"]  # Do not include company in your fields.
        # also note that since I didn't know your Offer's fields I used ["some_field", "other_field"] for fields
```

hope this solves your problem.

Comment: thanks that works. For the Model I just used `exclude` for the related company field.

Comment: You are welcome. Please note that it is not a best practice to use `exclude`/`__all__` in our serializers (because your model can change in the future and you might not want to have some of your fields in your serializer) but it's up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I think the use of the context for serializers will be a nice way to solve your case.

```
# serializers.py

class OfferSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Offer
        # now that we do not want company from the request body
        exclude = ["company"]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        # add company to the validated data from the context
        # we can feed the context from the APIView
        validated_data["company"] = self.context.get("company", None)
        ...
        return super().create(validated_data)
```

```
# views.py

class OfferList(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        # imo, we do not have to query for UserProfile
        # if the company is assigned to the UserProfile instance for the requestor
        # then, one2one relation can give us this
        context = {"company": request.user.userprofile.company}
        serializer = OfferSerializer(data=request.data, context=context)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```